# Transforming Coordinate in Picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

As i understand it, the picturebox coordinates system in .NET is defined such that the top point is the origin, with X pointing right, and Y pointing downwards.

Is there an in built .NET function to transform the default coordinates into cartesian? (Such that the origin is now at the bottom left, with X pointing right, and Y pointing upwards.)

Comment: Do you want to flip the picture vertically ? or your question is only about the Co-ordinate transform ?

Comment: I am asking about the transform only. Meaning instead of starting at the top-left point when I specify (0,0), I want it to start at the bottom-left point instead.

Comment: Nah, there's no any inbuilt library/class for that. To have a workaround for that, you can read the image and paint the picture box starting from lower point to upper point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no built-in function to convert to a Cartesian co-ordinate.  However, it would be simple to add one.  The only difference is the Y-axis value.

```
public static class PictureBoxExtensions
{
   public static Point ToCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
   {
      return new Point(p.X, p.Y - box.Height);
   }

   public static Point FromCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
   {
      return new Point(p.X, box.Height - p.Y);
   }
}
```

PS: Hope I got the math correct.

Comment: Am I crazy or do you really use the FromCartesian formula in either direction?

Comment: Try an example, say (1, 3) converts to (1, 1) in a 4 x 4 picturebox.Now use your formula to convert back. It fails./